# s-densities and conformal measures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

I recently learnt about s-densities:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold#s-densities_on_a_vector_space

For simplicity suppose that the vector space in this definition is \R. The prime example of a 1-density is certainly the one form dx. Each 1-density integrates to a translation-invariant measure on \R.

Is there a similar relation between s-densities and conformal measures?

Comment: What's a conformal density?

Comment: @Deane Yang: I think it should read conformal measure. In our situation an s-conformal measure on \R is a measure m on \R such that m(ax) = |a|^s m(x) for all non-zero scalars a and all x on \R (or subsets of the Borel sigma-algebra on \R).

Comment: What is an example of an $s$-conformal measure that is not of the form $c|x|^{s-1}\,dx$?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly a “conformal measure” is,
but densities do play a prominent role in the definition of conformal structures.

Consider a smooth manifold M.
A conformal structure on M is a Riemannian metric
on the weightless cotangent bundle T*<sub>0</sub>M=T*M⊗Dens<sub>−1/dim M</sub>(M).
Expanding this definition yields the usual notion of an equivalence class of ordinary Riemannian metrics.